# Execute FFmpeg command in Python on Raspberry PI

Tags: python, linux, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, popen

I used FFmpeg to record video on my Raspberry PI. The code is here:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -y -r 4 -i /dev/video0 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf:expansion=strftime:text='%Y-%m-%d %H\\:%M\\:%S': fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.8:x=w-text_w:y=h-line_h" -vframes 20 -vcodec mpeg4 out.mp4
```

I ran this code in terminal and it worked fine. However I need to run this by using Python. Then I wrote this code which shown below:

```
from subprocess import Popen
from os import system
x = "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf:expansion=strftime:text='%Y-%m-%d %H\\:%M\\:%S': fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.8:x=w-text_w:y=h-line_h"
result = ['ffmpeg', '-f', 'video4linux2', '-y', '-r', '4', '-i', '/dev/video0', '-vf', x, '-vframes ','20', '-vcodec', 'mpeg4', 'out.mp4']
Popen(result)
```

It is working for only a very short time (absolutely less than 1s). Anything wrong with it?

Comment: perhaps the python script is exiting and "killing" the running ffmpeg?

Comment: @rogerdpack Thought the same thing. Just did an experiment where I ran a simple infinite loop appending to a file, but it does not exit on the main program's exit. [It makes sense since `Popen` starts a whole new process.](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. It looks like you are having an issue with bash white space. On the command line, you enclosed the entire `-vf` option in quotes. In the python script, you created `x` as a string; `Popen` would interpret the string like the other arguments you have in the list and end up leaving it unquoted in the actual command run. On the command line, this would look like:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -y -r 4 -i /dev/video0 -vf drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf:expansion=strftime:text='%Y-%m-%d %H\\:%M\\:%S': fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.8:x=w-text_w:y=h-line_h -vframes 20 -vcodec mpeg4 out.mp4
```

So in effect, you would want:

```
x = '"drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf:expansion=strftime:text=\'%Y-%m-%d %H\\:%M\\:%S\': fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.8:x=w-text_w:y=h-line_h"'
```

Otherwise, that argument would be split at the white space in the date format when actually run by bash and cause some unexpected behavior.

(Sorry for the wall of text, just want to make sure that I'm not confusing.)

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I see what you mean. But it still finished so quick. I also tried using `call` to execute this code. Same problem with it. I wrote `call (["ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -y -r 4 -i /dev/video0 -vf \"drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf:expansion=strftime:text='%Y-%m-%d %H\\:%M\\:%S': fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.8:x=w-text_w:y=h-line_h\" -vframes 20 -vcodec mpeg4 out.mp4],shell=True)`. I think the problem is about the `drawtext` part. Because when I removed `-vr` part, it worked very well. (sorry about my english)

Comment: I assume you did in your actual program, but just in case, it seems you forgot the final quote for your `call` command (right before the closing bracket of the list). Other than that, I'm stumped, so you could be right. I don't have a camera for my raspberry pi at home, otherwise I'd try some more. Looks like you're on your own - good luck!

Comment: That is a typo, I wrote it in my script. I will try to figure this out. Truly appreciate your help.